# Нейронная сеть. Растет ошибка только на последнем сете обучающей выборки

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

Реализовал свою нейронную сеть и решил проверить ее работоспособность.

Структура нейронной сети: `3 входных нейрона, скрытый слой с 2 нейронами и 2 выходных нейрона`.

Обучающая выборка:

```
double_t** trainSet = new double_t * [] {
    new double_t[]{ 0, 0, 0 },
    new double_t[]{ 0, 1, 0 },
    new double_t[]{ 1, 0, 0 },
    new double_t[]{ 1, 1, 0 },
    new double_t[]{ 0, 0, 1 },
    new double_t[]{ 0, 1, 1 },
    new double_t[]{ 1, 0, 1 },
    new double_t[]{ 1, 1, 1 },
    new double_t[]{ 0, 0, 2 },
    new double_t[]{ 0, 1, 2 },
    new double_t[]{ 1, 0, 2 },
    new double_t[]{ 1, 1, 2 }
};
```

Первый и второй нейрон это значения операндов, а третий нейрон это номер операции 1 - &, 2 - | или 3 - ^ (xor). Эти числа нормализуются в 0, 0.5 и 1 соответственно.

Вот последние результаты работы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на приложенном скрине, ошибки во всех сетах, кроме последнего уменьшается. И если я из обучающей выборки уберу этот сет, то нейронная сеть будет отлично работать.

В чем может быть проблема? Как её исправить? Я проверил код функций и вроде не нашел ошибки, но если нужно попросите и я дополню вопрос кодом.

**Дополнено**

**Ошибка выходного нейрона**: `error = (ideal - output) * derivative(output)`

**Ошибка скрытого нейрона**: `error[i] = derivative(output[i]) * summa(weights[i][i+1] * error[i+1]`

Ошибка скрытого нейрона = значение производной * на сумму произведений веса между этим нейроном и нейроном следующего слоя, на ошибку нейрона следующего слоя.

**Ошибка для выбранного сета**:

`trainError = summa(ideals[i] - output[i]) / countOutputNeurons`

**Ошибка эпохи**: `epochError = summa(trainError[i]) / countSets`

Ошибка эпохи = сумма ошибок каждого сета разделенного на количество сетов.

**Дополнено**

Убрал умножение на производную при поиске ошибок выходных нейронов и нейронка наконецто обучилась, а не зациклилась.

И получил следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему то при входных значениях (1, 1) нейронная сеть хуже обучается.

Объясните пожалуйста кто разбирается почему так.

При начальной структуре (3 входных, 2 скрытых и 2 выходных), ошибки некоторых сетов например на 50 эпохе < 0.00001, у большинства в районе (0.01, 0.09) и только проклятого двенадцатого сета ошибка растет.

**Обновлено**

В общем проблема заключается именно в том, чтобы научить нейронную сеть операции `xor` и именно сету (1, 1). Ошибка уменьшается медленней чем при других сетах.

Добавил случайное перемешивание сетов каждую эпоху, что вроде ускорило обучение (раньше было в среднем 250+ эпох сейчас 150+).

Но тут есть еще одна проблема, решение которой я не могу найти. Если раз десять перезапустить обучение, то почему то может произойти такое, что нейронная сеть не будет обучаться и зациклиться на одних ошибках. Это как то случайно получается.

Comment: Активация какая? Для `xor` что-то кроме тангенса остальное всё плохо работает. Можете поиграться: https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=sigmoid&batchSize=10&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=2&seed=0.59175&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false

Comment: @CrazyElf сигмоидальная функция, хорошо попробую поменять функцию активации.

Comment: Хотя я посмотрел, иногда всё же и сигмоида тоже срабатывает. В общем, ещё может быть маловато скрытых нейронов, учитывая, что у вас ещё и 3 разных операции. Попробуйте вообще `xor` отдельно поучить от остальных операций, посмотреть, что получится.

Comment: @CrazyElf использовал тангенс функцию активации и в итоге значение первого выходного нейрона -1, а значение второго 1. И ошибка 2.5 всегда и не меняется.    Так же попробовал отдельно научить нейронку `xor` и раньше когда у меня был 1 выходной нейрон, то все работало, а сейчас 2 выхода и значения нейронов приблизительно 0.5 каждый и не меняются значения. Может у меня ошибка не правильно высчитывается? У меня много вопросов по поиску ошибки т.к. на разных источниках по разному находят ошибку. В вопросе дополню, то как у меня находится ошибка.

Comment: @CrazyElf и да я сразу попробовал количество скрытых слоев и нейронов увеличить. В итоге увеличил до 2 слоев по 10 и 5 нейронов, но безрезультатно

Comment: Тогда не знаю, к сожалению. `xor` непростая функция вообще. А инициализируете веса нейронов рандомно? А шаг обучения пробовали менять?

Comment: @CrazyElf да веса рандомно инициализируются. Пробовал менять гипер-параметры, но ничего не поменялось. Не подскажите, а поиск ошибок, которые написал в вопросе, правильны?

Comment: Нет, я поверхностно знаю нейронки, дальше мои знания заканчиваются, надеюсь кто-нибудь кто глубоко в теме поможет таки.

Comment: bias-ы, mini-batch обучение есть?(Надо/можно реализовать)

Comment: @Константин нейроны смещения есть, а про mini-batch не слышал

Comment: Минибатчи накопление градиента на части пакета,мудренно)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, у меня на Python(можно конвертировать) такая функция вспомогательная:

```
ready = False
y = 0
def operations(op, x, nn_params: Nn_params):
    global ready, y
    alpha_leaky_relu = nn_params.alpha_leaky_relu
    alpha_sigmoid = nn_params.alpha_sigmoid
    alpha_tan = nn_params.alpha_tan
    beta_tan = nn_params.beta_tan
    if op == RELU:
        if (x <= 0):
            return 0
        else:
            return x
    elif op == RELU_DERIV:
        if (x <= 0):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC:
        if (x > 0.5):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC_DERIV:
        return 1
    elif op == LEAKY_RELU:
        if (x <= 0):
            return alpha_leaky_relu
        else:
            return 1
    elif op == LEAKY_RELU_DERIV:
        if (x <= 0):
            return alpha_leaky_relu
        else:
            return 1
    elif op == SIGMOID:
        y = 1 / (1 + math.exp(- alpha_sigmoid * x))
        return y
    elif op == SIGMOID_DERIV:
        return (alpha_sigmoid * y * (1 - y))
    elif op == SOFTMAX_DERIVATE:
        return 1
    elif op == INIT_W_MY:
        if ready:
            ready = False
            return -0.567141530112327
        ready = True
        return 0.567141530112327
    elif op == INIT_W_RANDOM:
        return random.random()
    elif op == TAN:
        f = alpha_tan * math.tanh(beta_tan * x)
        return f
    elif op == TAN_DERIV:
        return beta_tan / alpha_tan * (alpha_tan * alpha_tan - y * y)
    elif op == INIT_W_CONST:
        return 0.567141530112327
    elif op == INIT_RANDN:
        return np.random.randn()
    else:
        print("Op or function does not support ", op)
```

Справа op это enum, попробуйте инициализацию, возьмите одну OR/AND или XOR, простые операции мне помогли TRESHOLD_FUNC и INIT_W_MY(так даже для "нерешаемой" XOR)

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что нужно сделать. Просто функцию попроще использовать,  и отдельно поучить xor и or/and?

Comment: Да отдельно, и функцию TRESHOLD_FUNC.Может выложите код, я попробую протестировать(может изменить), но не гарантирую, с С долго не работал.

Comment: Попробовал использовать функцию TRESHOLD_FUNC, но нейронка теперь вообще не учится, а застряла на одной ошибке.
Вот код [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/fMF6TKfE)

Comment: Скопировал, но пока не могу скомпилировать(у меня msys2-mingw), но сразу там видно что если используем (ideals - layers:=<что отдала сеть>)[* <производная>] то корректировка весов будет идти через минус т.е. weights(new) - =delta. Это важное и следует из математики.

Comment: Отредачил под компилятор mingw [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/Qye00cgx)
У меня 3 предупреждения выдает просто, а так все запускается.

Comment: `(ideals - layers:=<что отдала сеть>)[* <производная>]` не очень понял

Comment: Извиняюсь, с эти все правильно, я имел ввиду код в findOutError и backWards, проверил еще раз - т.е. корректировка весов правильная оказывается.

Comment: да компилируется)

Answer (score 0):

У вас оказывается довольно большая конфигурируемая сеть(не 3 слоя), и мне стала непонятна архитектура, поэтому предлагаю сначала изменить код так(более логично):

```
struct NeuralNetwork
{
private:
    
    

    struct Lay
    {
        int _in;
        int _out;
        Matrix<double_t> *matrix;  // веса
        Vector<double_t> *hidden; // вектор после функции активации
        Vector<double_t> *errors; // вектор ошибок
        

    double_t getRandomWeight() { return (double_t)(rand()) / RAND_MAX - 0.5; };  

    public:
        Lay(int in, int out) : _in(in), _out(out) // 1 слой
        {

            matrix = new Matrix<double_t>(_in, _out); // Создание матрицы весов

            srand(time(NULL));
            for (int row = 0; row < _out; row++) // ее заполнение
                for (int elem = 0; elem < _in; elem++)
                    matrix[row][elem] = getRandomWeight();

            hidden = new Vector<double_t>(out);
            errors = new Vector<double_t>(out);
        }
    };

    
    Vector<Lay> *net; // сеть как стек Слоев
    size_t count_layers;

    double_t E;
    double_t a;

    //Функция активации
    double_t (*activationFunc)(const double_t value) = [](const double_t value) {
        return value > 0.5 ? (double_t)1 : 0;
    };
    //Производная функции активации
    double_t (*derivativeFunc)(const double_t value) = [](const double_t value) {
        return (double_t)1;
    };

public:
    NeuralNetwork(const size_t *dimensions, const size_t size,
                  const double_t E = 0.5, const double_t a = 0.5)
    {

        this->count_layers = size;
        this->net = new Vector<Lay>(this->count_layers);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->count_layers; i++)
            this->net[i]=new Lay(dimensions[i + 1], dimensions[i]);
        
        this->E = E;
        this->a = a;
        
    };
...
}
```

Comment: Хорошо. Идею я понял, попробую переписать. Но вряд ли это решит проблему. Все, что мне хочется узнать это почему и как исправить проблему с последним сетом для xor. Почему он медленней обучается. Но идея с struct Layer мне понравилась.

Comment: Я тоже попробую доработать, честно говоря я думаю у вас где-то в архитектуре ошибка, правильная сеть должна работать.